# ModelSim Simulation Stops Earlier than Expected

Tags: verilog, hdl, modelsim, quartus

I am trying to run a testbench on ModelSim. I successfully compile and analyze my circuit code with only one warning:

```
Warning (20028): Parallel compilation is not licensed and has been disabled
```

This is my testbench scenario:

```
initial begin
   clk = 0;
end
        
initial begin 
    forever begin
        #1; 
        clk = ~clk;
    end 
end
        
initial begin
    inc_or_res = 1;
    ld_reg8 = 1;
    #10;
        
    inc_or_res = 0;
    #90;
end
```

As you can see it must run for at least 100ps with the delays I defined.

[image: Output waveform]

This is the simulation result I get. As you can see, it stops at 11ps. So I can't test my scenarios. What is the reason? It doesn't give me such error in my other testbenches.

Comment: ok i now found out that it gives (vsim-3601) iteration limit reached error.

Comment: The _Warning (20028)_ is not coming from Modelsim. The _(vsim-3601) iteration limit reached error_ means you either have a combinational oscillation loop, or some other infinite procedural loop. Look at the Modelsim User Manual for debugging tips.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok guys I found and solved the problem.

I was trying to implement a sequential circuit and it consists of a register for sure. The problem was I implemented this register by creating structural D flip flops and that created a combinational loop. This loop then caused the (vsim-3601) iteration limit reached error.

Here is how a register should be implemented:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/13.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vlog/vlog_pro_registers.htm

Answer (score 0):

Model sim is smart enough to understand that there is nothing else to be done after the `#90` delay. To save on simulation time, it stops the simulation just before this point. Which is why you are not seeing any waveform after this.

There are multiple ways to fix this:

1. Add a `$finish()` statement after the `#90` delay. This should keep the simulator alive. If this does not work, you can try adding some dummy transactions just before the `$finish()`.
2. In model sim GUI, there is an option to run simulation for a specified amount of time. You can use that. I'm sure there must be a command line equivalent if you don't want the hassle of clicking every time.
3. Technically, if there is any activity possible in the internals of your design (I can't check that since you haven't posted it), ModelSim should stay alive. Maybe check you design.

Comment: This is not the correct answer because the `forever` loop perpetually has something for the `clk` to do at a later time. You would need an explicit `$finish` or something in your Tcl run script to get the simulation to stop.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was driving a logic value from multiple modules. This resulted in a warning from modelsim when running simulation. Ignoring this warning caused the same problem as OP. But when I stopped driving the logic from two different modules the error went away.

Just posting here in case it helps anyone.

Comment: Just saying "it broke the simulation" probably isn't going to help many people. Please add details: expected output, error messages, how to fix. [Disclaimer - I work for Siemens EDA, but not on ModelSim]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure what's "unclear", if you've written any verilog the above should make sense. I had two different modules both driving the same output logic value. This was only resulting in a warning when using modelsim. But when running the simulation modelsim froze ignoring this warning.. What's "unclear" to you?

Comment: The solution is obviously don't drive the same logic from two separate modules as this is already a frowned upon practice.

Comment: I will change broke simulation to resulted in same problem as OPs but other than that I don't see why you're picking on my answer